# how do I get my friend to see my domain?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, webserver, ip-address, xampp

How do I allow my friend to see a web site via an unregistered domain name and not via a direct IP address.

I'm using Xampp 1.8.1 and have my ports forwarded.

Comment: I'd really love some help on this, cause It'd save me money and time hosting a forum from somebody else :).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be registered as a valid domain. Did you register it with a domain registrar? If it doesn't exist in DNS then it's not reachable by name. Your buddy can add www.bitgamerz.it to his host file and point it at your IP address, if all you want is for only his computer to resolve it.

Comment: I want everyone to be able to see it that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you want **everyone** to be able to specify your domain name in their browser and access your site then you must register that domain name with a recognised domain registrar - this is why people register domain names, there is no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Second Fiasco Labs. You domain name doesnt seem to be registered anywhere. You will first have to register that domain before someone can see it from the outside world. A work around could be if you made the domains IP your IP address and then you can send the IP address to your friend.

Comment: Well how would i make my dns or forum public as an actual name and not IP,cause I want to hide my IP address.

Comment: You will have to purchase the domain name. Find a registrar and purchase one. Once you have done that, you can point the domain name to your IP address.

Comment: Cant you do it for free though? I remember reading somewhere you could?

Comment: I doubt it. This all depends on how the traffic is going to reach your server.

The servers along the way will query the next servers DNS and so forth and they will say the domain does not exit. If your friend was on a local network then maybe.

What I can also suggest is if you try **hamachi** and see if you can set up a WAN. It's a suggestion, but it might work.

Comment: Okay Thanks a bunch for your help I'll look into it further.

Comment: "I want to hide my IP address" - even with a domain name, your IP address is not "hidden", it just doesn't show in the address bar. You might be able to do it for free if you are happy to use a subdomain of someone elses (already registered) domain. There might be services around that do this.